# Jquery - parsing returned AJAX Data into existing for fields

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, forms, populate

I'm using the following to read data from a database.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'loader.php',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  } 
});
```

This is returning : `[{"name":"Bob Green","ID":"1234"}]`

The data returned is being created by php and the format is simply being manually created and then echo'd back.  I can change how this is done it it make things easier.

Once I have the `data` returned I'd like to update an existing form. The form field names match the keys in the returned data. Most are text fields, but there are a couple of dropdown lists and checkboxes.

I have tried the following which I found on another question, but that didn't work.

```
function populate(frm, data) {   
    $.each(data, function(key, value){  
    var $ctrl = $('[name='+key+']', frm);  
    switch($ctrl.attr("type"))  
    {  
        case "text" :   
        case "hidden":  
        $ctrl.val(value);   
        break;   
        case "radio" : case "checkbox":   
        $ctrl.each(function(){
           if($(this).attr('value') == value) {  $(this).attr("checked",value); } });   
        break;  
        default:
        $ctrl.val(value); 
    }  
    });  
}
```

When I console logged the `key & value` it showed the data as indiviual letters not `name:Bob Green` & `ID:1234`

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that your `php` code return the data as string without the relevant header that tells your browser to handle the result is json.

To do so you can use:

```
$data = /* Some variable that contains your data */;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Another option is to tell your ajax request to handle the result of the request as json:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'loader.php',
    dataType: 'json', // This way jquery will try to handle the returned data as json object
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data);
    } 
});
```

Note that these are not the same:

```
console.log('[{"name":"Bob Green","ID":"1234"}]')
    [{"name":"Bob Green","ID":"1234"}]

console.log([{"name":"Bob Green","ID":"1234"}])
    [Object]:
        ID: "1234"
        name: "Bob Green"
```